# Unable to create Publishing site or unable to activate publishing feature on SharePoint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, publishing-site

- We are unable to create publishing sites on our SharePoint 2019 on-prem environment, we get below error as shown on the screenshot.
- We can create team site, however after creating teams site, if we try to activate the publishing infrastructure feature, it gives access enied error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please go to the root folder get denied in your error message, right-click and security tab.

Provided **network service** to set read and write permission to the root folder.